# TypeError when using Gridsome while building a Vue.js project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, gridsome

I'm using `Vue.js` and `Gridsome` to create a portfolio for myself. However, when I added a JSON file to contain my profile info in the site, I faced an issue. This is how I imported the file inside my `Index.vue` component:

```
<script>
import Intro from "~/components/Intro.vue";
import profile from "~/data/profile.json";

export default {
  components: {
    Intro,
  },
  metaInfo: {
    title: "Farzin Nasiri",
  },
  data: () => ({
    profile
  }),
};
</script>
```

and here is how I use it:

```
<Intro :personal="profile.personal" />
```

When I run the project in development (command: `gridsome develop`),  everything is ok and the data is read properly. However, when I want to build the project (command: `gridsome build`) which creates a build files in the `dist` folder, then this error happens:

```
Initializing plugins...
Load sources - 0.04s
Create GraphQL schema - 0.05s
Create pages and templates - 0.03s
Generate temporary code - 0.03s
Bootstrap finish - 0.67s
Compile assets - 13.28s
Execute GraphQL (6 queries) - 0.03s
Write out page data (6 files) - 0s
Could not generate HTML for "/":
TypeError: Cannot read property '__esModule' of undefined
    at i (/home/farzin/MyProjects/portfolio.farzinnasiri.com/node_modules/vue-server-renderer/build.prod.js:1:68670)
```

this is my project structure(src folder):

```
├── components
│   ├── Intro.vue
│   └── README.md
├── data
│   └── profile.json
├── favicon.png
├── layouts
│   ├── Default.vue
│   └── README.md
├── main.js
├── pages
│   ├── About.vue
│   ├── Index.vue
│   └── README.md
├── templates
│   ├── README.md
│   └── Work.vue
└── vendor
    └── bootstrap.min.css
```

here is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "portfolio.farzinnasiri.com",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gridsome build",
    "develop": "gridsome develop",
    "explore": "gridsome explore"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@gridsome/source-filesystem": "^0.6.2",
    "@gridsome/transformer-remark": "^0.5.0",
    "gridsome": "^0.7.0"
  }
}
```

I really don't get where the problem is and need help to solve it. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Gridsome & SSR

From the [Gridsome docs](https://gridsome.org/docs/assets-scripts/#without-ssr-support):

> gridsome build uses server-side rendering (SSR) to create a fully rendered page. If your Vue component does not support SSR ... it won't be rendered properly.
>
> we suggest you to encapsulate the component inside `<ClientOnly></ClientOnly>` tags and import the library inside Vue's `mounted()` handler.

The error you got is from `vue-server-renderer`, which is from Vue's server-side API. You'll need to implement the instructions above.

## ~ import

Also, without knowing how you've enabled loading JSON as a module (i.e. `~`) in development, perhaps that's an issue, because that doesn't work in the default Vue CLI environment.

Try removing the `~` from all imports:

```js
import profile from "@/data/profile.json";
```

Comment: I'm new to js and I don't think I enabled anything for loading json as a module. How ever everything is okay in the develop mode. also I change `~` to `..` ( added my project structure to the question) but no change. In develop mode everything is fine but the build process fails with that error

Comment: Ok, looks like your path was incorrect too.  I edited my answer to account for the new path info.

Comment: Unfortunately, this may be a Gridsome problem, because it's not reproducible in a typical Vue environment.  The `@` symbol is a Webpack special alias to the `src` directory, which your structure shows is the correct path.  The `~` would not work in a typical Vue CLI installation.  I'll take a look at the Gridsome docs.

Comment: Did you also remove the `~` from `Intro.vue`?  I would remove all `~` from your project and try to rebuild.  Use `@` instead and ensure that all paths are correct.

Comment: my project is here:https://github.com/farzinnasiri/developers-portfolio/tree/json.

Comment: One more suggestion for you:  Add the following to "vue.config.js" in your project root (not inside "src"):  `module.exports = { css: { sourceMap: true }}` and try to rebuild

Comment: there is no such file in my project. there is a `gridsome.config.js` which contans:```'module.exports = {
  siteName: "Farzin Nasiri | Portfolio",
  plugins: [
    {
      use: "@gridsome/source-filesystem",
      options: {
        path: "works/**/*.md",
        typeName: "Work"
      }
    }
  ]
};``` I added the `packag.json` file to my question. maybe I missed something

Comment: Ok, create it and try that `module.exports` code from my comment above.

Comment: I made that file and added the code but still the same problem

Comment: Ok, that's the best I can do.  Just FYI, the error is from `vue-server-renderer`, which is from Vue's server-side API.  Did you intend to be using SSR?  This wasn't mentioned in the question.  If this was unintentional, I suggest creating a brand new project without SSR and moving your code over to it.

Comment: that weird because I use gridsome to just create a static site and I didn't use anything to do server side rendering

Comment: how can I fix that? I just created a gridsome project and even once deployed the unfinished code on a server and is the build-ed files were completely static.

Comment: From the [Gridsome docs](https://gridsome.org/docs/assets-scripts/):  "gridsome build uses server-side rendering (SSR) to create a fully rendered page.  If your Vue component does not support SSR ... it won't be rendered properly."

Comment: "we suggest you to encapsulate the component inside `<ClientOnly></ClientOnly>` tags and import the library inside Vue's `mounted()` handler."  Time to read the docs.  I haven't used Gridsome so I can't help more, but hopefully this will be enough to help you sort it.

Comment: Thanks so much. the `client only ` tag work. Thank you

Comment: Which exact component did you encapsulate with `<ClientOnly>` tag to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the imported object to `vue` as follows:

```
data: () => ({
    myProfile:profile
}),
```

So you can use it as follows:

```
<Intro :personal="myProfile.personal" />
```